# How to handle wsgi-based server starting multiple processes that writes to the same file causing data loss?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, multiprocessing, mod-wsgi

I have a Flask web application that writes multiple CSV files with headers periodically every two minutes and this works fine when I run it with the Flask development server. However, I recently deployed my application with mod-wsgi production server and the code for writing to the CSV file didn't work as expected because mod-wsgi spins up multiple processes for my application and each process tries to write to the same CSV file which overwrites any data written by previous processes in the two min interval.

The pseudo code in question is:

```
# this is called every 2 mins because self.dataDict will have new data for every file every 2mins
def write_csv_files(self, destination: str) -> None:
    for filename in self.dataDict:
        filepath = os.path.join(destination + filename + ".csv")
        with open(filepath, "w") as fobj:
            # gen_row_helper returns a string of comma separated values for a file
            fobj.write(gen_row_helper(self.dataDict[filename]))
```

Example of a single CSV file

```
1694897668
name,place,number
Kevin, London, 123
Bob, Italy, 987
```

How to handle this situation when there are multiple processes that are writing to same csv file with headers?

The desirable situation is to overwrite the data only after 2 minutes as new data is available and after a downstream service has consumed this data but right now multiple processes end up overwriting data within the two minute interval which is causing data loss. The above code worked fine when there was only one process in flask development server but this can't be used in production.

Things I have already tried:

1. Open file in append mode ('a') so processes can append instead of overwriting but this results in multiple duplicate header lines in the final csv file and the file keeps growing unchecked since its not overwritten even after the 2 min interval
2. Create a file per process but this doesn't work because the downstream service which consumes these csv files only expects one file per filename

Comment: I  am having difficulty understanding a few things: (1) Is it the same files that are always supposed to be rewritten every 2 minutes or completely new ones or neither? How do you arrange for this to occur (I can't tell from your minimal code)? (3) This question is related to the prior question: What is the mechanism causing multiple process to write to the same files? No need to respond if you believe the answers should be readily apparent to me from your post. If that's the case I would be of no help to you anyway. Would [this](https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) help?

Comment: The app will generate new data so I have a service that collects this data and writes to csv file so the structure of the csv file will be same but data will be different every two mins. For example instead of Bob it could be Alice in next interval. This is a Flask app and I am using mod_wsgi to deploy it which creates multiple processes for my application and each process periodically tries to write its data to the same file. I can use that lock but then will also need some kind of clean up mechanism since these csv files will keep getting bigger in size

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock)? I once wrote a Flask application that had to do something similar, and a lock saved me. (I was using waitress so the lock was `threading.Lock`.) Just acquire a lock when you need write to the file; after the job is done, release it (you can also use the context manager style). This way, when other processes try accessing the file, they will have to wait for the current job to complete.

Comment: a lock will help me prevent race condition between two processes trying to write to file at the same time but this doesn't solve my problem of a process overwriting data which another process previously wrote. Maybe a process can append to the file instead of creating a new one but that would increase the size of the file unbounded. Do you have an example of how you did it?

Comment: I must apologise because I seem to have misunderstood your question. You need to append new rows within the 2-min interval then overwrite the file and start afresh, right? Then my code cannot help you here… If this is what you desire, I think you can probably use a custom file writer that only appends rows when the file is not empty, otherwise writes the header and the rows. As for cleaning up the files after the interval, perhaps a separate clean-up process is a good idea?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want. I was trying to avoid writing a cleanup process as it makes this logic more complicated but that will be the only choice I have if there are no other cleaner solutions

Comment: Do you have to clean it up every two minutes? If the exact time interval is irrelevant, I think you'd probably be better off if you use a file writer like this: first check the size, if it has not exceeded your limit, append the rows; otherwise overwrite it with the header and rows. See [documentation for the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects). Don't forget to use a lock. If two-minute is a must, I see no reasons why there shouldn't be a separate clean-up process with its own timer.

Comment: thanks enwioa! it doesn't have to be every two mins so yes I could have some custom logic like that instead of a separate process. I will check the csv module you linked above.